# What permission level is required for a user to sync a document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, sync

My users have the default 'Read' permissions set on SharePoint online, but the option to sync a document library is not available for them.  What is the minimum required permission level to be able to sync a document library?

Answer (score 1):

According to this blog:
http://nickheylen.com/2014/05/15/sync-error-we-cant-connect-to-the-specified-sharepoint-site/

You must either give the following persmission:

- Use remote interfaces
- Use Client Integrations features
- Open

or

> If you disable the ‘Limited-access user permission lockdown mode’ feature via ‘Manage Site Collection Features’ at the site collection level, the problem is also solved.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The permissions were set correctly, but I am testing the second step.

Comment: ok, hope it works out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure **synchronisation is enabled** at the site level:

1. Go to site settings.
2. Go to search -> search and offline availability
3. Select YES for option: **availability offlineclient**